# Exchange 2013 Remote-Powershell

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I am trying to manage an exchange server (2013)
I learned that directly loading PSSnapin for Exchange into a powershell is not the supported way and that I should use RS-Remoting like this

$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://exchangeserver.domain.local/powershell" -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $session

But when I connect to the exchange-server like that almost every object get serialized into string :/
Methods of objects (e.g. Database.DatabaseSize.ToBytes()) are not callable anymore, because serialization lost that information.

How can I use the full EMS in a remote powershell ?
Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issues with Exchange 2010 and all I could find was a forum posting saying that certain functionalities were not implemented in remote Exchange powershell. On the documentation for Exchange 2016 it recommends installing the [management tools locally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx).